# Required variables, best way to exit if empty?

Tags: php

When in a function a set of variables are required to complete a calculation, is it best to define the variables like below, with a conditional to 'exit' if the variables is empty? Or is the a better option?

```
$type = $row['item_options']['purchased_type']; 
if ( !$type ) { exit; }

$bf_required = 0;

$balance = 0;

$tour_id = $row['entry_id'];
if ( !$tour_id ) { exit; }

$places = $row['quantity'];
if ( !$places ) { exit; }
```

Comment: Does terminating the script meet your business needs?

Comment: @JohnConde Hi John. Not ideally. I need the calculation to be completed for everything to run correctly, but I am unsure how best to do this if all variables are required.

Comment: This is kind of an open ended question, so I am going to mark to close it as such; however, I'll leave you with my quick advice first. This is, in my opinion, a great example to use [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). If a variable isn't defined, throw an exception. Then, higher up in your logic, you can look for (and catch) these exceptions and display an error to the user such as "XYZ is a required field."

Answer (score 1):

If your application *requires* values to be set, then the best approach is to rely on Exceptions (that is what they are there for) to indicate something is awry.

For example:

```
$type = $row['item_options']['purchased_type']; 
if (empty($type)) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid type.');
}
```

You could even create your own custom exceptions extending the base `Exception` class, so that in catching them you can handle them appropriately. In this case, you might create an exception like:

```
class InvalidInputException extends Exception {}
```

And then you can throw/catch that specifically.

Comment: `You could even create own custom exceptions` - that's wrong thinking. There're some built-in types already which will cover most of the cases easily. Throwing base `Exception` (i.e. when you could i.e. `RuntimeException`) is bad as you cannot construct proper `catch` for it.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I wouldn't say it's the wrong thinking. Maybe, though, it would be better said *"You shouldn't use base the `Exception` class."* so that you can properly `catch` them. There are built in exceptions, but they aren't as specific as they could be. Maybe this example should be something like `class InvalidUserInput extends InvalidArgumentException {}`.

Comment: @Sam Perhaps, but that's basically about wording. What I meant is that to me his "default" approach is to throw instance of base `Exception` (I judge by presence of "even" in "you can even...") - and that's what I consider bad here.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I misread your key point...extending a more specific base class, instead of the ultimate base `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

> When in a function a set of variables are required to complete a calculation, is it best to define the variables like below, with a conditional to 'exit' if the variables is empty? Or is the a better option?

First of all I do not see any function in your code. The function itself should not bother if all arguments are present because it not its task at all. In fact PHP will slap you if you omit mandatory arguments:

```
function doTheCalculations($arg1, $arg2) {
...
}
```

i.e.

```
$x = doTheCalculations();
```

It's up to code that calls this method to ensure it got all the data needed and if not, complain itself. So you got this part wrong.

Also this code is wrong too, unless `$row['item_options']['purchased_type']` is `boolean`:

```
$type = $row['item_options']['purchased_type']; 
if ( !$type ) { exit; }
```

Hint: make your checks clear - you want to check the value -> check the value. You want to check the type? check the type properly. You want to check it exists? Use `isset()`, `defined()` etc.

Finally, if you want your `doTheCalculations()` method to tell you it cannot do the math because something is i.e. out of allowed range or invalid type I'd throw [Exception](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.exceptions.php):

```
if (!is_int($arg1)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException(".....");
}
```

alternatively, you can make your method always return `array` with keys `status` (`boolean`) and `result` (when `status` is `true`). You can add more fields if you want. Or you can do (but this is even more crappy and I do not recommend that as it simply not clean (even many PHP built in functions do this), assuming your `doTheCalculations()` is expected to return `int` you can return `false` if calculations cannot be made. But still, in this approach you do not know why this happened until you return the reason too.